# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus - Derivative of the integral

Tags: calculus

Given $\displaystyle y=\int^{\tan(x)}_0 \frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt$, how can I prove that $ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 1$ ?

attempt:

by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we have:
$\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{1+\tan^2(x)\cos^2(x)} = \frac{1}{1+\sin^2(x)}$

and not 1.

can anyone help with this problem?

thanks!!

Comment: You need to multiply the entire denominator $1+\tan^{2}x$ by $\cos^{2}x$, not just the $\tan^{2}x$.

Answer (score 4):

Put $$F (t)=\int_0^t \frac {du}{1+u^2}$$

then $$F'(t)=\frac {1}{1+t^2} .$$

$$y=F (\tan (x)) $$

$$\frac {dy}{dx}=F'(\tan (x))(\tan (x))'$$

$$=\frac {1}{1+\tan^2 (x)}(1+\tan^2 (x)) $$

$$=1$$

Answer (score 1):

The FTC implies
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}
 = \frac{\sec^2 x}{1+\tan^2 x}
 = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x}
 = 1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Just note that $\int{\frac{1}{1+x^2}}=arctan(x)+C$. So integrating you get that 
$y=arctan(t)|_{0}^{tan(x)}$=x$. Then differentiating with respect to x gives the result.

Comment: only If x∈(−π2,π2) then arctan(tanx)=x !

Comment: Sure. What's your point? Did you specify that it could not be.